# Even after pushing element in the array.Array is showing empty outside the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to upload multiple images using cloudinary in node.js application.
Storing every image URL in an array. But my array is empty outside the loop. Can't understand why.

```
const postCreate = (req,res,next) => {
    req.body.post.images = [];
    const file_length = req.files.length;
    let arr = [];
    //console.log(req.files);
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req.files.forEach((file,index) => {
            i = index;
            cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file.path)
                .then(image => {
                    //console.log(image);
                    req.body.post.images.push({
                        url: image.secure_url,
                        public_id: image.public_id
                    });
                    console.log("array", req.body.post.images);//there array is containing the element which is pushed.
                });
            console.log("arr", req.body.post.images);//but there it is showing empty array .Can't understand why array is empty.
        });
        resolve();
    }).then(() => {
            Post.create(req.body.post)
                .then(post => {
                 //console.log(req.body.post.images);
                    res.redirect(`/posts/${post.id}`);
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error will saving posts from db ', err);
                    return next(err);
                });
    });
```

Comment: It's because `cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload` is async function. You are printing your array just after this async function call. You should wait for the promise using `then` or modern `async await` construction.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: and also cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload is already a promise you dont need to wrap it around another promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the uploads is asynchronous and returns a promise.

You need to have all those promises resolve before moving on to the final `then()`

You can map an array of those promises and use `Promise.all()` to return the full array to the final `then()`

Something like:

```
const doUpload = (file) => {
  // return the upload promise
  return cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file.path).then(image => {
      return {
        url: image.secure_url,
        public_id: image.public_id
      };
    });
}

const postCreate = (req, res, next) => {
  // map array of individual upload promises
  const uploadPromises = req.files.map(doUpload);

  Promise.all(uploadPromises).then(imagesArray => {
    // assign new array to post body
    req.body.post.images = imagesArray;

    Post.create(req.body.post)
      .then(post => {
        //console.log(req.body.post.images);
        res.redirect(`/posts/${post.id}`);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error will saving posts from db ', err);
        return next(err);
      });
  }).catch(err=> console.log('One of the uploads failed'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd log message actually gets called first while the array is empty because the code in the then block is waiting for something asynchronous to complete.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is your print function fire before loop is complated so you have to use async-await for proper solution and learn more about this topic

> please refer https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs for your solution

it describe the `async await` for your proper output